# Putting another array as property into another array failed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tried to play with spread of es6, didn't get it quite right

```
const arr1 = [{
  gap: 10
}, {
  gap: 20
}, {
  gap: 30
}]
const arr2 = [{
  english: null
}, {
  france: null
}]
```

How can I produce a new array, which `arr2`'s property become apart of `arr1`?

From jsfiddle:

```
    //expected new_arr to be
/*[{
  gap: 10,
  english: null,
  france: null
}, {
  gap: 20,
  english: null,
  france: null
}, {
  gap: 30,
  english: null,
  france: null
}]*/
```

failed attempt 
https://jsfiddle.net/swu94gd5/

Comment: how will the final array look like

Comment: your code in fiddle works fine, why did say it failed?

Comment: @ZhangBruce compare the actual result with expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```js
const arr1 = [{
  gap: 10
}, {
  gap: 20
}, {
  gap: 30
}]
const arr2 = [{
  english: null
}, {
  france: null
}]

const new_arr = arr1.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, ...arr2));

console.log(new_arr);
```

Note:

I originally had

```
const new_arr = arr1.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, ...arr2));
```

but changing `arr1[0].gap` will change `new_arr[0].gap` - the code in the snippet fixes that

Re comment *can you explain ur definition of object assign in ur head?*

I don't have a definition in my head

I use the definition in documentation

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.
>
> Object.assign(target, ...sources)

[MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: I often use Object assign, but couldn't have a clear definition in my head, can you explain ur definition of object assign in ur head?

Comment: @JaneEmelia - I've added to the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]** This is actually solving the wrong problem since I read a bit too quickly, but I'll leave the original code here as an example of how to do something similar. Thanks to **Jaromanda X** for pointing this out.

As Jaromanda X noted, the correct solution is

```
const new_arr = arr1.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, ...arr2));
```

If you were trying to zip the properties from the objects in `arr2` into `arr1` instead, this is how you'd do it:

```
const new_arr = arr1.map((obj, i) => ({
  ...obj, ...arr2[i]
}));
```

Comment: does that produce the expected output? i.e. Array of 3 objects **each** with `gap`, `english` **and** `france` properties?

Comment: @JaromandaX Woops, read the expected output a bit too quickly, thanks for pointing that out. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "..." syntax works also as the Spread operator for Arrays, so when you wrote: `...arr2` you're effectively spreading the items of that array. However, you could do something like this:

```
const new_arr = arr1.map(obj => ({
...obj, ...arr2[0], ...arr2[1]
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also use `array#map`  and `array#reduce` to join objects in both the arrays.

```js
const arr1 = [{gap: 10}, {gap: 20}, {gap: 30}]
const arr2 = [{english: null}, {france: null}]

var result = arr1.map(obj => {
  return arr2.reduce((r, o) => {
    return Object.assign(r, obj, o);
  },Object.create(null));
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that uses the "reduce" method. Works like a charm:

```
const arr1 = [{
  gap: 10
}, {
  gap: 20
}, {
  gap: 30
}]
const arr2 = [{
  english: null
}, {
  france: null
}]

const new_arr = arr1.map(obj => ({
  ...obj, ...arr2.reduce((acc, langObj) => ({...acc, ...langObj
  }), {})
}))
console.log(new_arr)
```